# Splitting stacked dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like

```
         age sex      values
time                        
2015      10   F    589628.0
2015      10   M    458390.0
2015      11   F    108018.0
2015      11   M    764350.0
 ....
2000      60   M     34676.0
2000      60   F     45488.0
```

I would like to create data frame like

```
         age   F           M
time                        
2015      10   589628.0  458390.0    
2015      11   
 ....
2000      60   45488.0   34676.0
```

reducing the rows by half and adding a column. I have tried to do this with pivot, but no avail.

```
df.pivot(columns='sex', values='values')
```

but this returns

```
Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

Any ideas how can I cleanly split the dataframe without writing a tedious function to do it?

Cheers, Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't confirm this but it should be

```
df.set_index(['age', 'sex'], append=True)['values'].unstack().reset_index('age')
```

Comment: I think this is faster.

Answer (score 1):

Using [pivot_table](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) and [reset_index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
In [17]: df
Out[17]: 
      age sex    values
time                   
2015   10   F  589628.0
2015   10   M  458390.0
2015   11   F  108018.0
2015   11   M  764350.0

In [18]: newdf = df.reset_index().pivot_table('values', ['time', 'age'], 'sex').reset_index()

In [19]: newdf.columns.name = None

In [20]: newdf = newdf.set_index(['time'])

In [21]: newdf
Out[21]: 
      age         F         M
time                         
2015   10  589628.0  458390.0
2015   11  108018.0  764350.0
```